# Show that $\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathrm{ln}\big(\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}\big)\Big] < 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing, expected-value

We know that $X > 0$ and that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$. 
Show that $\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathrm{ln}\big(\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}\big)\Big] < 0$.
Could someone show me a way to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: use Jensen inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve this using Jensen's inequality. Since $\log()$ is a concave function, by Jensen's inequality we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}[\log(\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]})] \leq \log(\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}])$$
Since X is strictly positive (so the expectation isn't zero), and the expectation exists (so it is finite), we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X]} = 1$$
So:
$$\mathbb{E}[\log(\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]})] \leq \log(\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}]) = \log(1) = 0$$
$$\mathbb{E}[\log(\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]})] \leq 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Usually when logarithms and expectations are involved, Jensen's inequality is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ln\mathbb{E}[X]=c<\infty$ then $\mathbb{E}[\ln(\mathbb{E}[X])]=\ln(\mathbb{E}[X])$.

$$\mathbb{E}[\ln(X/\mathbb{E}[X])]=\mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]-\mathbb{E}[\ln(\mathbb{E}[X])] = \mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]-\ln(\mathbb{E}[X])$$

Via Jensens-Inequality we know that $\ln(\mathbb{E}[X])\geq \mathbb{E}[\ln(X)]$ because the logarithm is concave.